# Perform non-native MacOS terminal command - truncate to create new file - In Java code

Tags: java, macos, terminal, exec, truncate

I have followed several question answers but still can't seem to get a file created using the truncate method in code, as I would be able to in terminal.

I get no errors from the code actually running, which is bizarre.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

Given that I have CD'd to the Desktop:

```
truncate -s 10M ./files/myFile.txt
```

Using truncate like this should create a new file in the files directory called "myFile.txt" with a file size of 10mb.

**My code**

I am assuming that the terminal command will run from source, so I will have to include the full path to the directory

```
    String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String fileDir = "/Desktop/files/";
    String fileName = "myFile.txt";
    String fullPath = homeDir + fileDir + fileName;

    try {
      String[] cmd = {"sh", "-c", "truncate", "-s",  "10M",  fullPath};
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      fail("something went wrong: " + ioe);
    }
```

As I mentioned above, there are no errors when running the code. However the file is not showing up in my system at all.

Comment: `./files/myFile.txt` and `~/Desktop/filesmyFile.txt` is certainly not the same file name, so are you sure you're looking for the file in the right place? *Hint:* Notice e.g. the missing `/` between `files` and `myFile.txt`.

Comment: The `truncate` command does not natively exist in `macOS`.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, typo. I included an `/` on the end of the fileDir now. I printed out the `fullPath` and got **/Users/username/Desktop/files/myFile.txt**. Also I just checked that running truncate with `./files` from Desktop in terminal works and it does. Or am I missing the point of your comment?

Comment: Try doing `which truncate` and post the output.

Comment: @l'L'l - Do you mean to use the string array: `{"which", "truncate", ...}`?

Comment: @l'L'l - Sorry I wrote that last comment before I saw you asking to post the output. The output is `/usr/local/bin/truncate`

Comment: Maybe try your command as `String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/local/bin/truncate", "-s",  "10M",  fullPath};`

Comment: @l'L'l still no luck :-(

Comment: I'm thinking you may not need the `'/bin/sh', '-c'` portion of the command, try `"/usr/local/bin/truncate", "-s", "10M", fullPath`

Comment: Aha! Spot on! Thanks for the help @l'L'l! A lot of guides on here this sort of thing, but nothing about non-native mac commands.

Answer (score 0):

Solution came from a back and forth with user @l'L'l.

Since `truncate` is a non-native MacOS terminal command, it was required to include the full path to where it was installed.

```
which terminal
```

gave me

> /usr/local/bin/truncate

I could then add this in place of `truncate` in my original code.

Also, since truncate is not performed with any other keywords or shorthand, I was not required to include the `sh` or the `-c`.

The final `process` code was then:

```
String fullPath = "/Users/username/Desktop/files/myFile.txt
String[] cmd = {"/usr/local/bin/truncate", "-s",  "10M",  fullPath};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

All of the string pieces could also be extracted into their own variables:

```
String truncate = "/usr/local/bin/truncate";
String fileSize = "10M"
```

for ease of reading:

```
String[] cmd = {truncate, "-s",  fileSize,  fullPath};
```